# How to set custom value to export in laravel excel in version3.1

Tags: excel, laravel

I tried to integrate laravel excel to matwesite excel version 3.1 and exported. In previous i used version 2.1, there i can easily set condition like

```
        $birth_date = new \DateTime($patient->dob);
        $meet_date = new \DateTime($patient->visit_date);
        $interval = $birth_date->diff($meet_date);
        $age = $interval->format('%y');
        'BMI' => ($age >= 15) ? $patient->bmi : '',
```

Here is my exportable DataExport.php code

```
public function collection()
{
    $patient_data = DB::table('histories as hi')
    ->join('doctors as d','d.id','=','hi.doctor_id')
    ->join('patients as p','p.id','=','hi.patient_id')
    ->join('addresses as ad','ad.id','=','p.address_id')
    ->join('patient_infos as pi','pi.id','=','hi.patient_info_id')
    ->join('users as u','u.id','=','d.user_id')
    ->orderBy('hi.id','DESC')
    ->select('hi.id as hid','hi.created_at as visit_date','hi.diagnosis as diagnosis','hi.sec_diagnosis as sec_diagnosis','u.name as dname','p.name as patient_name','p.age as dob','p.reg_mem as reg_mem','p.gender as sex','ad.name as address','p.centre_patient_id as ecohid','pi.*')
    ->get();

    return $patient_data;
}
```

i use withheadings and here is my heading

```
public function headings(): array
{
    return [
        'Date','ECOH ID','Pt. Type','Patient Name','Age','Sex','Address','Doctor Name','Pri. Diagnosis','Sec. Diagnosis','SBP','DBP','Pulse','Oxy','Temp.','Weight','Height','BMI','Edema','Anemia','Jaundice','HTN','DM','Salt Intake','SLT','Smoking',
    ];
}
```

Now how can i set the data value [like version 2.1](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u7ipeL-ua8cBhnatsRsJi9O4e8mNuYadOGkn5eGgJTI/edit)

Comment: can you explain better what should be the expected result?

Comment: as you can see the [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u7ipeL-ua8cBhnatsRsJi9O4e8mNuYadOGkn5eGgJTI/edit) **bold** where i set the individual column with value and set condition if needed. Example: in database sex is store 0 or 1, in export i want to show 0 = Male and 1 = Female

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by placing the code

```
\DB::raw('IF((p.gender = 0),"M","F") as sex')
```

use DB::raw then condition, true, false